# A function wrapped in a computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have seen many times how people wrap their function in a computed property to be able to call it with any value.

Here is an example

```
<template>
  {{ myComputedFunction(2) }}
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const refVariable = ref(5)

const myFunction = (a: number) => {
  return a * refVariable.value
}

const myComputedFunction = computed(() => myFunction)

setTimeout(() => {
  refVariable.value = 10
}, 5000)
</script>
```

Yes, at first the function will return 10, and after 5 seconds it will return 20. But how right is it to do this?

Comment: Your code is correct and this is the right way to do it

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Not really, it's technically correct but redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workable approach but it doesn't serve a good purpose. A parametrized computed can be used to cache a function. Since creating new functions is fast in modern JS engines, and proxies that are used by computeds are relatively slow, this primarily makes sense if this involves some computations outside a function that are based on reactive values:

```
const myComputedFunction = computed(() => {
  // some expensive preliminary computation

  return (a: number) => ...
)
```

Since `myFunction` is not reactive value, `myComputedFunction` is computed only once, `myComputedFunction.value === myFunction`. There's no practical difference between `{{ myComputedFunction(2) }}` and `{{ myFunction(2) }}`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Boussadjra Brahim's comment. its absolutely correct.

first time: 2 * refVariable(5) = 10

after 5 seconds refVariable value changes to 10, so your computed property will be called again.(computed property will be called every time, one of their dependencies changes.)

second time: 2 * refVariable(10) = 20

Comment: Computeds are recomputed only when one of reactive values used in the body of computed callback is changed, so the result is efficiently cached. myFunction itself is not reactive and stays constant, no benefit from caching it. myComputedFunction(2) results in multiple myFunction calls on each template renders, but there's only 1 myComputedFunction call on initial render